# SecStatusCode value returned does not equate to anything in the Enum?

Tags: c#, xamarin, enums, xamarin.ios, keychain

I am trying to remove a service from my keychain in my Xamarin project doing the following:

```
public void DeleteAccounts()
{
    foreach (var service in Services)
    {
       var query = new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword);
       query.Service = CreateAlias(service);

       var statusCode = SecKeyChain.Remove(query);
    }

}
```

But the `SecStatusCode` returned by the `SecKeyChain.Remove(query)` is the value `-34018`

This doesnt equate to any value in the [SecStatusCode](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.Security.SecStatusCode/) Definitions

[image]

So what does this value equate to in my enum? I can't begin to diagnose the problem knowing what the return code equates to

Comment: Issue with ios: more info here: https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_10/xamarin.ios_10.0/#Upstream_Issues_in_Xcode

Comment: workaround here: [https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44361](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44361)